# getting error as Cannot read property 'key' of undefined angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, fabricjs, angular11

I am getting error for my below code

error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined at EditorComponent.push.xD4D.EditorComponent.setFillColor (editor.component.ts:634)`

ts

```
    setFillColor(swatch: any): void {
    this.palettes.selected = swatch;
    this.props.fill = swatch.key;
    this.setFill();
    if (!this.props.canvasImage) {
        console.log('say hi')
        this.canvas.backgroundColor = this.props.canvasFill;
        this.canvas.renderAll(); 
    };
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [cpPosition]="'right'" [cpPresetColors]="customColors" [cpOKButton]="true" [cpAddColorButtonText]="'Speichern'" [cpAddColorButton]="true" [cpOKButtonClass]="'btn btn-light btn-sm'" [cpSaveClickOutside]="false" [(colorPicker)]="props.canvasFill"
           [style.background]="props.canvasFill" [value]="props.canvasFill" (cpPresetColorsChange)="updateColorPresets($event)"
           (colorPickerChange)="setFillColor()"/>
```

Comment: In your html `(colorPickerChange)="setFillColor(p)`. What's `p` in that case?

Comment: I have removed that p i just checked adding paramerter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your input data like:

```
setFillColor(swatch: any): void {
  if (!swatch) {
    debugger
  }
```

And see call stack in dev tools.

By some of the case your function got "undefined" as argument. You should define reason why it happens and maybe write code to process this case.

Comment: I tried like this 

    setFillColor(swatch: any): void { 
        if(!swatch){
            this.palettes.selected = swatch;
            this.props.fill = swatch.key;
            this.setFill();
        } else if(!this.props.canvasImage){
            console.log('say hi')
            this.canvas.backgroundColor = this.props.canvasFill;
            this.canvas.renderAll(); 
        }       
    }

still getting same error

Comment: This code not should fix error, you still try get value from key of undefined

Comment: i changed my html like OP but i got this error 

Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at EditorComponent_div_50_Template_input_colorPickerChange_4_listener

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not passing any value to method `setFillColor` from your HTML code.

You can pass current value as :

```
(colorPickerChange)="setFillColor($event.target.value)"
```

Comment: Thanks Naresh 

Now I am getting this error 

 Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at EditorComponent_div_50_Template_input_colorPickerChange_4_listener

Comment: try with `(colorPickerChange)="setFillColor($event.currentTarget.value)"`

Comment: I modified like this  (colorPickerChange)="setFillColor($event.currentTarget.value)"

Comment: just pass $event in method, and put debugger in your method definition and check which value you are getting.

Comment: as you told i put event there and i put debug in the code 

setFillColor(swatch: any): void { 'swatch = #323232'
this.palettes.selected = swatch;    swatch = #323232'
this.props.fill = swatch.key;   props is getting undefined and swatch getting the color value and key is undefined
this.canvas.backgroundColor = this.props.canvasFill here I am getting the color value for canvasFill


Partially worked

Comment: actually what i want is  if i selected shape the color has to change but with current code it is changing both background and shape color

Comment: setFillColor(swatch: any): void {
            this.palettes.selected = swatch;
            this.props.fill = swatch.key;
            this.setFill();
            if (!this.props.canvasImage) {
                console.log('say hi')
                this.canvas.backgroundColor = this.props.canvasFill;
                this.canvas.renderAll(); 
            };
        }

partially worked thanks when i select shape or when i select the text that particular object has to change the color

Comment: can you please help on this question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66518906/issue-fabric-js-applying-background-color-for-shapes-and-background-angular