# issue fabric js applying background color for shapes and background angular

Tags: angular, angular8, fabricjs, angular11

I am facing a issue in fabricjs the issue is

1. i have default background with my current code i was able to change the background color
2. if i place any object or text if i want to change the background color of that object changing to transparency
3. I am trying to change the shape color but background color is changing.
4. actually i found what is the issue in the below html i have props.canvasFill i think there should be two parameters because if you see my ts code

Here is my HTML

```
**<input type="text" class="form-control" [cpPosition]="'right'" [cpPresetColors]="customColors" [cpOKButton]="true" [cpAddColorButtonText]="'Speichern'" [cpAddColorButton]="true" [cpOKButtonClass]="'btn btn-light btn-sm'" [cpSaveClickOutside]="false" [(colorPicker)]="props.canvasFill"
           [style.background]="props.canvasFill" [value]="props.canvasFill" (cpPresetColorsChange)="updateColorPresets($event)"
           (colorPickerChange)="setFillColor($event)"/>**
```

Here is my ts code in html curerntly it is having canvasFile i have to use **fill and canvasfill** I am not getting how to use that

```
 props: any = {
    canvasFill: '#ffffff',
    canvasImage: '',
    id: null,
    opacity: null,
    fill: null,
    stroke: null,
    strokeWidth: null,
    fontSize: null,
    lineHeight: null,
    charSpacing: null,
    fontWeight: null,
    fontStyle: null,
    textAlign: null,
    fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
    TextDecoration: '',
    scale: 1,
    angle: 0
};

    setFillColor(swatch: any): void {
        this.palettes.selected = swatch;
        this.props.fill = swatch.key;
        console.log(this.props.fill, '& ' ,swatch.key);
        this.setFill();
        if (!this.props.canvasImage) {
            console.log('say hi')
            this.canvas.backgroundColor = this.props.canvasFill;
            this.canvas.renderAll(); 
        };
    }

console.log(this.props.fill, '& ' ,swatch.key); i am getting Undefined & undefined
```

[image]

Comment: what's the value of `swatch` variable you are getting ?

Comment: I am getting undefined & Undefined

Comment: not swatch.key.. just swatch variable.  write first line in your method as `console.log(swatch)`. What's printed in console

Comment: @NareshJ getting color code

setFillColor(swatch: any): void {
        console.log(swatch);

Comment: #d82727 Color code like this

Comment: console.log(this.palettes.selected); i got the color code

Answer (score 1):

`swatch` is the actual color code you are getting which user has selected and it's string.

So you are getting `undefined` when you read property of `swatch` which is string and string does not have such `key` property.

So replace line `this.props.fill = swatch.key;` with `this.props.fill = swatch;` and you don't need first line `this.palettes.selected = swatch;` unless you are referring it somewhere else.

Comment: this.props.fill = swatch.key;
            this.props.fill = swatch; 
            this.setFill();
            if (!this.props.canvasImage) {
                this.canvas.backgroundColor = this.props.canvasFill;
                this.canvas.renderAll(); 
            };

is this correct

Comment: with the current code the background color is change and

 when i select the shape i am applying new color inital it is applying for background when i release it is applying for the shape

Comment: `<input type="text" class="form-control" [cpPosition]="'right'" [cpPresetColors]="customColors" [cpOKButton]="false" [cpAddColorButtonText]="'Speichern'" [cpAddColorButton]="true" [cpOKButtonClass]="'btn btn-light btn-sm'" [cpSaveClickOutside]="false" [(colorPicker)]="props.canvasFill"
               [style.background]="props.canvasFill" [value]="props.canvasFill" (cpPresetColorsChange)="updateColorPresets($event)"
               (colorPickerChange)="setFillColor($event)"/>`

This is my html

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: can you please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588866/load-images-dynamically-in-multiple-canvas-using-fabricjs-angular